# problemas con express a la hora de recibir peticiones

Tags: nodejs, typescript, express, http

estoy haciendo un backend de una red social para mejorar mi lógica, les dejo el [repositorio](https://github.com/Enzo-taiel/backend) de git para que puedan ver el código, tengo varias rutas, pero las rutas que me dan problemas son [publicaciones](https://github.com/Enzo-taiel/backend/blob/main/src/controllers/publications/publications.ts), [sugerencias](https://github.com/Enzo-taiel/backend/blob/main/src/controllers/friends/sugerencias.ts) y [notificaciones](https://github.com/Enzo-taiel/backend/blob/main/src/controllers/notificaciones/notifications.controllers.ts), el error que recibo es

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

es fácil de entender el problema, traducido seria algo así `No se pueden establecer encabezados después de que se envían al cliente`,

según la ruta a la que hago la petición, por consola me muestra la lineal donde se encuentra el error, pero los errores me los da cuando intento responder al usuario, ej: `res.status(200).json(*/ algo */)` y si quito esas lineal lógicamente el endpoint no retorna nada.
Busque por todo el backend algo que pueda dar con el error, pero no pude encontrar nada o tal vez no lo puedo percibir, llegue a pensar que el error, debe ser por como estoy haciendo las peticiones al back, espero obtenga ayuda. gracias.

Quiero agregar algo que tal vez pueda a llegar a ser útil, las primeras veces que el cliente hace las peticiones aparece el error, después de ciertos reintentos la peticiones se realizan con éxitos sin ningún problema.

este es el controlador de la ruta `/api/v1/pr/all_post`

```
export const Publicaciones = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { user }: any = req;
  const users = [user._id];
  try {
    const usr: IUsuario | null = await Usuario.findById(user._id);
    if(usr){
      for await (let element of usr.seguidos) {
        users.push(element);
      }
      const publicaciones = await Publicacion.find({
        usuario: { $in: users },
      })
      .populate("likes")
      .populate("usuario")
      .populate({path: "comments", populate: {path: "usuario"}})
      .sort({ createdAt: 1 })
      return res.status(200).json(publicaciones)
    }else{
      return res.status(500).json({message: 'credential invalid'})
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Intentalo mas tarde." });
  }
};
```

este es el controlador de la ruta `/api/pr/v1/segerencias`

```
export const Sugerencias = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { user }: IUsuario | any = req;
  const exclude = [user._id];
  for await (const friend of user.seguidos) {
    exclude.push(friend);
  }
  for await (const item of user.solicitudes_enviadas) {
    exclude.push(item);
  }
  for await (const item of user.solicitudes_recibidas) {
    exclude.push(item);
  }
  try {
    const friends = await Usuario.find({ _id: { $nin: exclude } })
      .populate("amigos")
      .limit(4);
    return res.status(200).json({ sugerencias: friends });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Error al buscar sugerencias" });
  }
};
```

esta es mu ruta `/api/v1/pr/notificaciones`

```
export const Notificaciones = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { user }: any = req;
  try {
    const notifications: INotificacion[] | [] = await Notificacion.find({
      _id: { $in: user.notificaciones },
    })
      .populate("usuario")
      .populate("publicacion")
    return res.status(200).json(notifications);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    return res.status(400).json({message: "No se encontraron documentos."});
  }
};
```

> actualizacion

estube testeando la api con `postman` e `insomnia` y las rutas responden bien, no veo ningun problema, puede ser que el error este en el cliente, esto es posible ?

Comment: Te sugiero que uses un sistema de logger que haga que tus errores sean más *verbosos*, es decir que muestren más información para que puedas detectar cuál linea y en qué archivo se ubica la llamada fallida. Por otro lado, los links que pusiste no funcionan. Saludos

Comment: tenia el repositorio privado, ya lo puse publico, la informacion que me muestra por consola es exactamente eso, me aclara donde esta el error, lo agregue a la pregunta

Comment: Pues como sugerencia, usa una sentencia `return` justo antes de esa llamada a `res` para que la función finalice y no procese alguna linea adicional que llame en otra parte a dicho método. Si puedo revisaré tu repo a ver si encuentro el fallo. Saludos

Comment: Pasa por el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) para comentarte más sobre tu código. Saludos

Comment: @Enzo Hola ¿Puedes apoyarme con la lógica para tener sección de notificaciones tipo Facebook? Uso igual nodejs aunque la parte frontend uso Angular.

Answer (score -1):

Básicamente te dice que estás retornando dos res.status().json(). el primero te lo acepta y llega correctamente, pero de repente el sistema detecta que llegó un segundo res.status().json() y cómo el sistema no sabe que hacer, lo que te manda es

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

Desconozco dónde exactamente se produce porque no eh revisado el código. sería geníal si pudierás mostrar el N°de la linea donde se produce el error.

Comment: la consola me dice que el error es donde esta el `res.status().json()` dependiendo de que petición realice, ej: la ruta `/api/v1/pr/notificaciones` me dice que el error esta cuando respondo a la petición, ósea `return res.status(200).json(notifications);`, lo mismo con las demás rutas, el error es cuando retorno la respuesta a la consulta, probé quitando el `return` y agregándolo de las direfentes rutas pero el error persiste

Comment: Entonces si el error te marca ese res.status().json() significa que ese res.status(),json() esta demas. que ya respondiste a la petición. algo me dice que el catch te está capturando también y ahí es donde se produce el conflicto. por otro lado si estas trabajando con Express. te recomiendo que uses los middelwares y los handler error. Intenta separar bién tu lógica de negocio de las consultas hacía tu base de datos para que tengas un codigo mas limpio y modularizado

Comment: que middleware ?

Comment: tienes que sacar ese return al momento de ocupar res.status().json() porque lo que haces es estar pasando al siguiente middelware. basta con colocar solo res.status().json()

Comment: ok quitare todos los `return` de los endpoint para verificar...